# (Infinite hat)-guessing problem

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory

> $2$ men are playing a game: they are wearing countably infinitely many hats on their heads. The hats are either black or white with probability $\frac 12$. They see the other's man hats but cannot see the hats on their own head. Without communicating with each other, they simultaneously point to a hat on their own head. They win the game if the two hats they've chosen are both white. The players devise a strategy before hats are put on their heads.
>
> I'm looking for a strategy with a success probability greater than $\frac 13$.

If both players choose a random hat, they win the game with probability $\frac 14$.

If both players choose the position of the first white hat that is on the other player's head, they have probability $\frac 1 3$ of success: if you let $X_i$ and $Y_j$ denote the colors of the $i$-th and $j$-th hats for the first and second player respectively, you're looking for $$P\left(\bigcup_{i,j\geq 1}\left( (X_i=w)\cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{i-1}(Y_k=b)\cap  (Y_i=w) \cap (Y_j=w)\cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{j-1}(Y_k=b)\cap  (X_j=w)  \right)\right)$$

which, under obvious independence assumptions, is $\frac 13$.

Any ideas ? It would also be interesting to extend the game to $n$ players. In that case, the strategy I suggested has probability success $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ which gets asymptotically close to $\frac 1{2^n}$ (the chance of success of the dumbest strategy).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the second strategy.  Suppose the first white hat is in slot $i$ on the first players head and $j$ on the second with  $i >j$.  Then the $i$ player points to a black hat on his own head.  Thus this strategy fails unless $i=j$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ah...but there is a $\frac 13$ probability that $i=j$, as $\frac 14+\frac 1{16}+\cdots=\frac 13$.  Surprising.

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem. Do you have reason to believe that there should be a strategy with success probability greater than $\frac13$?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think that $\frac13$ might be optimal. To guide efforts towards finding either a better strategy or a proof of optimality, it would be useful if you'd say something about the source of the problem and the reason you're looking for a better strategy.

Comment: @joriki the source is http://www.brand.site.co.il/riddles/201607q.html They're asking for a strategy that is asymptotically $\frac{1}{\log n}$. Maybe $\frac 13$ is optimal, I don't know

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: Thanks for the source. Unfortunately it seems that this falls under [our contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) and should be locked until the contest ends. (That wasn't the reason I asked, I genuinely wanted to know the source in order to think about the problem better.)

Comment: This is an excellent question, and it is a sub-part of of the linked contest question. I am uncertain about whether to lock this question or not, and for now I've decided not to. [If someone thinks this is an error, let mods know and we'll reconsider it].

Answer (score 2):

You can get them to win with probability 7/20.
As of today it is still an open problem whether we can do better, but there is an upper bound at 0.361607.

See here: https://mathmondays.com/hat-game and https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4711.

Also see this related question: [Coin Flipping Riddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247698/coin-flipping-riddle/4247733#4247733).